# meter element is incompatible between safari and chrome

Tags: html, css, web

I'm trying to use the meter as a password strength meter in my web page. In order to change the appearance, I set the css to

```
.passwordMeter {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.passwordMeter::-webkit-meter-bar {
    background: whitesmoke none;
}
```

The problem is when I include "-webkit-appearance: none;", the meter doesn't show up in chrome, and if I delete that, the appearance doesn't change in safari.
How could I solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622911/styling-meter-bar-for-mozilla-and-safari

Comment: According to [this bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=632510) it sounds like the behaviour was deliberately introduced in Chrome to workaround a more pressing issue.  I don't think there is a CSS fix - it's best not to rely on non-standard features if you require cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: I have found a solution and postet it to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38622911/styling-meter-bar-for-mozilla-and-safari/72304567#72304567

The trick was to set border-color: transparent for the meter element, you can also use any other color it is not visible.